# Windows environment OpenACC

Tags: windows, openacc

I would like  to start developping OpenACC program and I have few questions to ask : 
Is it possible to execute OpenACC code on AMD gpu ?

If so, I'm looking for a compiler available for windows environment. I spent like hour to find nothing, I'm going desperate to find anything that could allow me to compile Openacc directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a few compilers that support AMD devices.  You can see the targets offered by PGI at: http://www.pgroup.com/resources/accel.htm#targets.  This includes several AMD Radeon devices.

I believe Pathscale also targets AMD devices (http://www.pathscale.com/) but I'm not sure if they have a Windows compiler available.  Please contact them directly for more information.

Hope this helps,
Mat

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at this !